# How to submit a form from CWEB(content editor web part) to sharepoint list using jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have created a form using html and on click of the submit button the contents should be updated to a particular sharepoint list. I have tried using javascript but it is still non-functional. Please help me to rectify the problem.

I have tried with sharepoint javascript.

```
var siteUrl = 'https://arcadiso365.sharepoint.com/teams/BTHub_UK/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx';
 function AddNewListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.(siteurl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoFeedback');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);


    var name=document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("name").ClientID %>').value
    var comm=document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("comment").ClientID %>').value
    var title=document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("title").ClientID %>').value

    oListItem.set_item('Title',title);
    oListItem.set_item('Name', name);
    oListItem.set_item('Comments', comm);

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The form successfully takes the data. But it is not updated in the specified list. I need the list to hold the values submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, what's the error you got?

Here is my tested script for your reference(insert the script into content editor web part directly [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRreGP3g0Mg)).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx";
var clientContext;
var website;
var listItem;


function myFunction(){

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    var list=website.get_lists().getByTitle("list6");    

//Object for creating Item in the List    

var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();    

 listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);    

    listItem.set_item("Title",$("#name").val());    

    listItem.update(); //Update the List Item    

    clientContext.load(listItem);    
    //Execute the batch Asynchronously    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item created: ' + listItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```